# android using gcm without google play service install?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm using Android GCM without installing Google Play Service on my device?
What's the way to send push notifications with GCM and not install Google Play Services?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible - GCM [requires](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client#play-services) Google Play Services to function properly.

> To write your client application, use the GoogleCloudMessaging API. To use this API, you must set up your project to use the Google Play services SDK, as described in Set up Google Play Services SDK.

Answer (score 1):

you can use old GCM that don't need to googlePlayService to be installed, but it deprecated, see [this link](http://androidexample.com/Android_Push_Notifications_using_Google_Cloud_Messaging_GCM/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=119&aaid=139)